# Tools for validating HTML 5 offline cache manifests?

Tags: html, offline

HTML 5 includes the ability to specify how to [run the web application offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html). As I'm about to start authoring these things, I'm looking for a tool to validate the syntax of the [offline cache manifest](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#manifests) files. Ideally, I'd run it as part of the build process.

*I'm aware HTML 5 is still in draft, but waiting isn't an option. I may write one, but I was hoping someone had knocked one out already.*

Comment: that would be awesome.  the html5 manifest is currently a huge pain.  Works differently in different browsers....

Answer (score 2):

I use the simple bash script to generate cache.manifest each time I build my application:

```
#!/bin/bash

MANIFEST_FILE="cache.manifest"
echo "CACHE MANIFEST" > ${MANIFEST_FILE}
echo "#Created at `date -Ru`" >> ${MANIFEST_FILE}
echo "" >> ${MANIFEST_FILE}
echo "CACHE:" >> ${MANIFEST_FILE}
find . -type f | cut -c 2- | grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' | grep -v '^/cache.manifest$' >> ${MANIFEST_FILE} 
echo "" >> ${MANIFEST_FILE}
echo "NETWORK:" >> ${MANIFEST_FILE}
echo "/api" >> ${MANIFEST_FILE}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://manifest-validator.com/.  You can upload or link to your manifest file and it will validate it for you.